# Separable metric space with no isolated points.

Tags: general-topology, analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a separable metric space with no isolated points and $(X,\mathcal{B}(X),\mu )$ is a measure space such that $\mu(X)<\infty$.

How to prove that for all $\epsilon >0$, there exists a dense open subset $O$ such that $\mu (O)<\epsilon$?

Comment: Can we assume that $\mathcal{B}(X)$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $X$?

Comment: My teacher didn't mention that assumption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $X$ is a separable metric space, there is a countable base for the topology. Let $B_1,B_2,B_3,\dots$ be a sequence of nonempty open sets such that every nonempty open set contains some $B_n.$

Let $\epsilon\gt0$ be given. Let $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2,\epsilon_3,\dots$ be a sequence of positive numbers such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\epsilon_n\lt\epsilon.$

Since $\mu(B_n)\lt\infty$ and $X$ has no isolated points, we can find more than $\frac{\mu(B_n)}{\epsilon_n}$ disjoint nonempty open sets inside $B_n,$ and then one of them must have measure less than $\epsilon_n.$ Thus, for each $n,$ we can choose an open set $U_n\subseteq B_n$ with $\mu(U_n)\lt\epsilon_n.$

Let $U=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty U_n$; then $U$ is dense in $X$ and $\mu(U)\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mu(U_n)\lt\sum_{n=1}^\infty\epsilon_n\lt\epsilon.$